# A Philosopher's Dream

Tags: knowledge

> I am heavier than most, but I still run faster than you.
>   Some mistake me for a fool, yet everyone else loves me.
>   Even as centuries pass and empires disappear too--
>   I stay by their sides, faithfully.

Hint:

> The title is also intended to be a hint.

Comment: I was thinking you are rot13(gur cnfg) but that might be a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Gold. Gold is heavier than most, and there is fool's gold. Gold does not break down, and it lasts a long time. The title is a reference to the legendary philosopher's stone, which turns base metals into gold. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher%27s_stone

Thanks to @hexomino for this part:

> "I still run faster than you" is a reference to a gold medal.

Comment: "Faster than you" could be a reference to a rot13(tbyq zrqny)

Answer (score 1):

You are

> The Moon.
>  You are heavier than most things people use and see everyday, and yet the actual speed of the Moon (say with respect to a fixed point on Earth) is very high.

The title

> refers to [Cicero](https://theconversation.com/in-1968-apollo-8-realised-the-2-000-year-old-dream-of-a-roman-philosopher-109097)

Everyone loves you

> It is quite pleasant to be outside at night and see the moon. Also, people in *love* sometimes go on "honey*moon*" after getting married.

But

> [Some mistake you for a fool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jy09K37phFM). Also, *fools* may get it wrong when they hear *full moon* and understand *fool moon* instead.